# Regular expression to parse key value pairs with quotations

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to parse key value expressions with Ruby with the following format:

`foo-bar:bar foo:"bar 1" "bar 2":"foo 3" "bar 2 \"var\"":"foo 3"`

Should yield:

```
Key: foo-bar     Value: bar
Key: foo         Value: bar 1
Key: bar 2       Value: foo 3
Key: bar 2 "var" Value: foo 3
```

Is this possible with regular expressions? Keys and values can be an unquoted string 
without white spaces, or a quoted string with white spaces.

I have the following:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+|\"[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+)\"\s*\:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+|\"[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+\")
```

Comment: that regex is working?

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/kuZts0X1AJ No it is not working. I can get it match a set of KVP, but not able to pick out all the KVPs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve most of your problems:

```
("(?:\\.|[^"])*"|[^\s]*):\s*("(?:\\.|[^"])*"|[^\s]*)
```

[rubular](http://rubular.com/r/ARSoiJlk8x)

A more elaborate option will be:

```
(?:"((?:\\.|[^"])*)"|([^\s]*)):\s*(?:"((?:\\.|[^"])*)"|([^\s]*))
```

Which will capture without the quotes, in ruby it will look like this:

```
string = 'foo-bar:bar foo:"bar 1" "bar : 2":"foo \" 3" "bar 2 \"var\"":"foo 3"'

string.scan(/(?:"((?:\\.|[^"])*)"|([^\s]*)):\s*(?:"((?:\\.|[^"])*)"|([^\s]*))/).map(&:compact)
# => [["foo-bar", "bar"], ["foo", "bar 1"], ["bar : 2", "foo \\\" 3"], ["bar 2 \\\"var\\\"", "foo 3"]]
```

[rubular](http://rubular.com/r/xTjmDjo8Li)

Comment: This works, but you have to remove the double quotes to make the answer complete.

Comment: Added an option removing the double quotes

Comment: Interesting... why replacing ':' with '=' does not have the same effect for
'foo-bar=bar foo="bar 1" "bar = 2"="foo \" 3" "bar 2 \"var\""="foo 3"' ?

Comment: `(?:` is a special sequence!

Comment: @Gatis - you need to replace only the `:` in the middle (...`*))` __`:`__ `\s*`...) the rest are indeed special characters (for grouping) and are not literal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/([^:]*):\s*("[^"]*"|[^\s]*)/
```

[see on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/QT6ULFKuJE)

You still have to remove the quotes though. And it does not work with escaped quotes in the value.

Comment: This mostly works, but if there’s a `:` inside the key name, it [fails](http://rubular.com/r/dmbVwpbhUQ).

Comment: What about `foo-bar:bar foo:"bar 1" "bar 2":"foo \" 3" "bar 2 \"var\"":"foo 3"`?

Comment: True. Also if colons are in the value. And as I added, also if there are escaped quotes in the value it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'foo-bar:bar foo:"bar 1" "bar 2":"foo 3" "bar 2 \"var\"":"foo 3"'

s.scan(/(?<!\\)"((?:[^"]|\\")*)(?<!\\)"|([^\s:]+)/).flatten.compact
.each_slice(2).to_h
# =>
# {
#   "foo-bar"           => "bar",
#   "foo"               => "bar 1",
#   "bar 2"             => "foo 3",
#   "bar 2 \\\"var\\\"" => "foo 3"
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a non-regexp solution, then this very simple parser should do the job:

```
def kv(s)
state = :unquoted
result = [""]

  s.chars do |c|
    if state == :unquoted
      case c
      when ':', ' '
        if result.last.length > 0
          # next
          result << ""
        end
      when '"'
        state = :quoted
      else
        # write
        result.last << c
      end
    elsif state == :quoted
      case c
      when '"'
        # next
        result << ""
        state = :unquoted
      when '\\'
        state = :escaped
      else
        # write
        result.last << c
      end
    elsif state == :escaped
      #write
      result.last << c
      state = :quoted
    end
  end
  result.pop
  Hash[*result]
end
```

Test:

```
s = 'foo-bar:bar foo:"bar 1" "bar 2":"foo 3" "bar 2 \"var\"":"foo 3"'
kv s # => "foo-bar"=>"bar", "foo"=>"bar 1", "bar 2"=>"foo 3", "bar 2 \"var\""=>"foo 3"}
```